# How to skip jacoco coverage check during build?

Tags: maven, jacoco, skip, jacoco-maven-plugin

In our project we use `jacoco-maven-plugin` and during the build I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:check (jacoco-check) on project my-project: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details.
```

I know that it's better to fix coverage and so on. But sometimes I just need to quickly build a project. 
Is there some kind of parameter for this purpose? Like `mvn clean install -Dskip.jacoco.check=true` or other way to quickly skip this check?

Comment: Yes. Almost like that. The check goal has a skip parameter: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#skip - so it would be -Djacoco.skip=true - it seems this skips all of the jacoco goals. If you don't want that maybe temporarily move the check goal into a profile you can activate when back on track?

Comment: @wemu Can you put your comment into an official answer? I find it also works for me

Comment: @wemu 's comment worked for me, too. I posted it as answer below. All the credits go to him :)))

Comment: @IKo I'd also add the tags `Jacoco` and `skip`

Comment: You may preserve coverage checking and continue build. See `jacoco:check` parameter: [haltOnFailure](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#haltOnFailure). Set it up in your `pom.xml` or use a ` mvn jacoco:check -Djacoco.haltOnFailure=false`

Answer (score 48):

As @wemu commented below OP u can use `-Djacoco.skip=true` command line option to skip Jacoco code instrumentation and coverage report generation temporarily. Examples:

```
mvn clean test -Djacoco.skip=true
mvn clean verify -Djacoco.skip=true
mvn clean package -Djacoco.skip=true
mvn clean install -Djacoco.skip=true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set `jacoco.haltOnFailure` property to `false` when executing build and this will do the checks but will not fail the build.

Example:

```
mvn clean install -Djacoco.haltOnFailure=false
```

Docs are [here](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html).

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip code coverage for some java files using pom.xml or else sonar-project.properties.

Ex: use the below plugin, give the packages of java files which does not require code coverage in the  tag

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-report</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/sbi/mdcm/v1_0_0/insurancequote/autogen/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>com/sbi/mdcm/v1_0_0/insurancequote_resources/autogen/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.80</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/com/sbi/mdcm/v1_0/insurancepolicy_adapter/osi/model/*.java
```

Comment: Beeing able to exclude classes can be useful, especially if they are conflicting w/ Jacoco and make the build fail. This is not what OP asked for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Wlad's answer above, I made a simple batch script over the MVN command.  I set the default behavior, since this is for my development environment, to disable/skip the Jacoco coverage analysis.  Create this script in your `%MVN_HOME\bin%` directory.  Adjust for your preferences:

`m.bat`:

```
@echo off

@REM Facade over maven command

if [%1]==[-j] goto jacoco
echo Skipping Jacoco analysis
mvn %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 -Djacoco.skip=true
goto end
:jacoco
mvn %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7

:end
```

This allows the following invocations:

- for code coverage: `m -j clean site`
- and to build my package (no code coverage): `m clean package`

Flavor to your liking. :-)